# Not able to drop schema in DB2 Using ADMIN_DROP_SCHEMA Stored Procedure

Tags: db2, database-schema

I found at several places to be able to drop a schema in DB2 along with all of its contents (indexes, SPs, triggers, sequences etc) using

```
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_DROP_SCHEMA('schema_name', NULL, 'ERRORSCHEMA', 'ERRORTAB');
```

However, I am getting the following error while using this command:

```
1) [Code: -469, SQL State: 42886]  The parameter mode OUT or INOUT is not valid for a parameter in the routine named "ADMIN_DROP_SCHEMA" with specific name "ADMIN_DROP_SCHEMA" (parameter number "3", name "ERRORTABSCHEMA").. SQLCODE=-469, SQLSTATE=42886, DRIVER=4.22.29
2) [Code: -727, SQL State: 56098]  An error occurred during implicit system action type "2". Information returned for the error includes SQLCODE "-469", SQLSTATE "42886" and message tokens "ADMIN_DROP_SCHEMA|ADMIN_DROP_SCHEMA|3|ERRORTABSCHEMA".. SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, DRIVER=4.22.29
```

Can anyone help me suggest what's wrong here? I tried to look at several places but didn't get any idea. It doesn't seem it's an authorization issue. Using DB2 version 11.5.

Comment: Does the error table exist already? Is it clean? Do you  have rights on it?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the [ADMIN_DROP_SCHEMA](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0022036.html) procedure parameters incorrectly, assuming you are CALLing the procedure from SQL and not the CLP.

The third and fourth parameters cannot be a literal (despite the documentation giving such an example), instead they must be  host-variables (because the the procedure requires them to be input/output parameters).

If the stored-procedure completes without errors it sets these parameters to NULL. so your code should check for this.

If the stored-procedure detects errors, it creates and adds rows to the specified table and leaves the values of these parameters unchanged, and you must then query that table to list the error(s).  You should drop this table before calling the stored procedure otherwise the procedure will fail with -601.

Example:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @

drop table errschema.errtable@

set serveroutput on@

begin 
   declare v_errschema varchar(20) default 'ERRSCHEMA';
   declare v_errtab    varchar(20) default 'ERRTABLE';
   CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_DROP_SCHEMA('SOMESCHEMA', NULL, v_errschema, v_errtab);
   if v_errschema is null and v_errtab is null
   then
       call dbms_output.put_line('The admin_drop_schema reported success');
   else
       call dbms_output.put_line('admin_drop_schema failed and created/populated table '||rtrim(v_errschema)||'.'||rtrim(v_errtab) );
   end if;
end@
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use global variables if you would like to use `ADMIN_DROP_SCHEMA` outside of compound SQL

E.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VARIABLE ERROR_SCHEMA VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT 'SYSTOOLS';
CREATE OR REPLACE VARIABLE ERROR_TAB    VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT 'ADS_ERRORS';
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SYSTOOLS.ADS_ERRORS;
CALL ADMIN_DROP_SCHEMA('MY_SCHEMA', NULL, ERROR_SCHEMA, ERROR_TAB);
```